# Reshaping Layer into Skew-Symmetric Matrix in Keras

Tags: r, keras, deep-learning

Say I have a keras model (for example)

```
layers_NE<-keras_model_sequential()
layers_NE %>% layer_dense(units=Height,
                           activation = "relu",
                           trainable=TRUE,
                           input_shape = 4,
                           bias_initializer = "random_normal") 
          %>% layer_dense(units = (d^2),
                           activation = "linear",
                           trainable = TRUE,
                           bias_initializer = "random_normal")
```

I want to reshape the last layer to a *skew-symmetric matrix* output for example like this `c(a,b,c)-> c(c(a,b),c(b,c))` *(here c(a,b,c) is notation for the output of my network)*

So far I've tried this:

```
layers_NE %>%layer_reshape(input_shape = (d^2),
                           target_shape = c(d,d)
                           )
```

the output is of the correct shape but it isn't symmetric.  How can I make that happen?

Comment: What do you mean with a symmetric matrix? A square matrix is symmetric depending on its values, so it depends on the output of the dense layer. I guess you cannot control your network to be symmetric. If the goal of the problem you are working on is to find a symmetric matrix, you could define your loss function to penalize nonsymmetric outputs.

Comment: Basically I want to map a vector in R^(d(d-1)/2) a matrix's upper triangular part and lower triangular part using those entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More frugal version which supposed to do exactly what you want without extra neurons. Also had to introduce two transpositions just to apply `k_gather` to correct axis, because of the way how `k_gather` is exposed to R (in python you could just pass `axis=1` as argument to `tf.gather`):

```
Height <- 10
d <- 7
layers_NE<-keras_model_sequential()
layers_NE %>% layer_dense(units=Height,
                          activation = "relu",
                          trainable=TRUE,
                          input_shape = 4,
                          bias_initializer = "random_normal") 
%>% layer_dense(units = (d * (d+1) / 2),
                activation = "linear",
                trainable = TRUE,
                bias_initializer = "random_normal")
%>% layer_lambda(f=function(x) {
    selector <- array(0, dim=c(d^2))
    ind <- 0 # zero-based indicies needed here
    for (i in 1:d) {
        for (j in i:d) {
            selector[(i-1) * d + j] <- ind
            selector[(j-1) * d + i] <- ind
            ind <- ind + 1
        }
    }
    t_ind <- k_constant(selector, dtype='int32')
    k_permute_dimensions(k_gather(k_permute_dimensions(x, pattern=c(2,1)), t_ind), pattern=c(2,1))
})
%>% layer_reshape(input_shape = (d^2),
                  target_shape = c(d,d))
```

Upd. here is the similar piece, but in Python - the only important difference is that `tf.gather` can be called with `axis=1`:

```
def select_symmetric(x, d):
    selector = np.zeros(d*d, dtype=np.int32)
    ind = 0
    for i in range(d):
        for j in range(i, d):
            selector[i * d + j] = ind
            selector[j * d + i] = ind
            ind += 1
    t_ind = tf.constant(selector, dtype=tf.int32)
    return tf.gather(x, t_ind, axis=1)

Height = 10
d = 7
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(Height, 'relu', input_shape=(4,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(d * (d + 1) // 2, 'linear'),
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(select_symmetric, arguments={'d': d}),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(d, d)),
])
```

Comment: would it be possible for you to use the python formulation since I'm not very fluent in R?  I'd be happy to pass on the points i nthat case :)

Comment: Updated with the python version, though not 100% sure I understood your request correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 ways to achieve that. The easier one would be to do exactly as you did initially - introduce at some point a layer with 2-dimensional square output per example (d,d) which is not symmetric and then make it symmetric by adding it to its own transposed version. It might look like the following:

```
layers_NE<-keras_model_sequential()
layers_NE %>% layer_dense(units=Height,
                           activation = "relu",
                           trainable=TRUE,
                           input_shape = 4,
                           bias_initializer = "random_normal") 
          %>% layer_dense(units = (d^2),
                           activation = "linear",
                           trainable = TRUE,
                           bias_initializer = "random_normal")
          %>%layer_reshape(input_shape = (d^2),
                           target_shape = c(d,d)
                           )
          %>% layer_lambda(f=function(x) {
                             (x + k_permute_dimensions(x, pattern=c(1,3,2))) * 0.5
                           })
```

After you add the model with its own transposed version the results will be symmetric (no real need to average here I guess). There is a bit of an redundancy in this solution since you have to actually train d^2 units instead of d(d+1)/2. Other than that it should be ok.

The second - a bit more frugal solution would be to actually create d(d+1)/2 units and put them into (d,d) shape in a way that non-diagonal elements are "duplicated". I believe what you are looking for is to create e.g. a lambda layer using `k_gather` function. But the only saving would be that you train less neurons on one of the layers.

Comment: Yes, I'm exactly interested in the second way.  Would you know how to do that?  I would be more than satisfied.

Comment: Does the tranpose thing work for you? For gather you need to get to a state where you have a 3d integer tensor of dimensionality (Batch, D, D) which is just a repeat of (1, D, D) tensor Batch times on first dimension and values in 2nd, 3rd dimension are e.g. [[1, 2], [2, 3]] for d=2, or [[1,2,3],[2,4,5],[3,5,6]] for d=3, etc. (using 1-indexed notation of R).

Comment: I would probably stick to transpose thing - I really don't see any problems from that except for the performance-wise (and only if that layer is somehow the largest for you). Keras + tensorflow make it way too painful to construct such simple things. And R doesn't make it easier either.

Comment: I guess the transpose would do the job but since I want to make very deep networks the frugal method is basically what I've been thinking about for a while